# MySQL - NULL safe NOT equal operator

Tags: mysql, null, equals

I am just curious - I know about NULL safe equal operator `<=>`, but is there some NULL safe NOT equal operator? Or I have to always use something like this:

```
(tab.id != 1 OR tab.id IS NULL)
```

or someone prefers

```
!(tab.id <=> 1)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
COALESCE(tab.id, 0) != 1
```

Can be used here if you like it. I goes through the parameters, and returns the first value that isn't `NULL`. In this case if it's `NULL`, it will compare `0 != 1`. Although it may use more signs, it's still easier to manage instead of being forced to always have opposite "booleans" as a solution in those cases.

Read documentation for [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: I think this is the preferred method as this query will also function on SQL Server too.  The best method is to not have nulls and have a proper default , but the source data cannot always be controlled by the developer.

Comment: Unfortunately if you don't know the value on the RHS of this comparison, you don't know what to COALESCE() your NULL to!

Comment: This works if you want to compare tab.id with a value but it does not work if you want to compare two fields like tab.id with tab_childs.tab_id.

Comment: For what it's worth, the method outlined in another answer `!(tab.id <=> 1)` seems to get a performance boost as compared to this one. I ran explain on a table with a few thousand rows and the former gets a better value in the `filtered` column.

Answer (score 20):

I found that `NOT (NULL <=> 1)` works and I think it is also ISO standard compliant, but is cumbersome.  A better way to show using column names would be like this: `NOT (tbl.col1 <=> 1)`

Comment: `<=>` is not standard SQL, it's a MySQL extension. The standard equivalent null-safe comparison is, typically for SQL, much more verbose: `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`.

Answer (score 10):

Now *MySQL* does not have a *NULL-safe not equal* operator.

Using *MySQL* the most universal solution is:

```
!(tab.id <=> 1)
```

or

```
NOT tab.id <=> 1
```

because it will work properly if even in place of `1` you will use `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the RHS of the comparison `IS NOT NULL`:

```
COALESCE(tab.id != 1, 1)
```

Or

```
COALESCE(tab.id != 1, TRUE)
```

will give you the correct result.

Whether this is better more readable than:

```
(tab.id != 1 OR tab.id IS NULL)
```

Is debatable..

I'd also be tempted to filter out the `NULL` logic first with comparisons, so I don't have to think about them! I'd probably write your first equation as:

```
(tab.id IS NULL OR tab.id != 1)
```

Performance will depend on prevalence of `NULL`s however.