# MySql returning NULL on comparison

Tags: mysql, comparison

I've been running into an issue.

Can someone explain why

```
SELECT (null <> 'TEST STRING')
```

and

```
SELECT (null != 'TEST STRING')
```

returns NULL instead of a boolean true as you would expect?

I'm not looking for a solution, rather for an explanation why SQL behaves like this.

You would expect any comparison in no matter what language to return a boolean.

Comment: I don't see why that would help to write an explenation of the behaviour of mysql

Comment: Why would you ever compare strings with NULL?

Comment: This might be of your interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16234854/3132718

Comment: @Ai.G. I need to check if a field called status does not contain 'processing' for example, it can be null or another status, I want to select all rows that do not contain 'processing', so including the rows that have status=null

Comment: One options is to use [<=>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) (NULL-safe equal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arithmetic comparison cannot be performed with NULL operators. So when you perform arithemetic operation with NULL like `<>` and `!=` it is giving you NULL(a *meaningless value*) against your expection as boolean value.

The [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) can be referred for explanation as to how NULL works in MySQL.

Also note that in MySql NULL is special, it means `unknown` value while in programming it means `undefined value`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

> Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also
>   NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.
>
> In MySQL, 0 or NULL means false and anything else means true. The
>   default truth value from a boolean operation is 1.

You may use `is null` or `is not null` comparison

```
mysql> select  'TEST STRING' is not null;
+---------------------------+
| 'TEST STRING' is not null |
+---------------------------+
|                         1 |
+---------------------------+
```

Comment: I do not want to check if a value is NULL, I want to check if x is not y
and if x is null and y is a string, why does it return null instead of a boolean?