# Condition expression in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Alright, this one is driving me nuts. Below is a part of my MySQL Stored Procedure:

1. This one work fine as expected

   `IF (@prevfldSubDepartmentID != paramSubDepartmentID) THEN
     statements; 
   END IF;`
2. But this one doesn't

   `IF ((@prevfldSubDepartmentID IS NULL) OR (@prevfldSubDepartmentID != paramSubDepartmentID)) THEN
    statements;
   END IF;`

This gives error ONLY when @prevfldSubDepartmentID is NULL:

```
ErrorCode   1064
Message     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
SQLState    42000
```

I am wondering what could be wrong with this. I'm probably missing something very basic. Does anyone see any problem with the second code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
ISNULL(@prevfldSubDepartmentID,0) = 0
```

Edit; Thanks for the downvote, a quick google for MYSQL ISNULL reveals this as the equivalent for MySQL:

```
ISNULL(expression)
```

Comment: the DBMS here is MySQL not SQL Server

Comment: Not familiar with the inbuilt functions for MySql, thought it would have an equivalent. 
 The point was rather than checking directly for NULL, use an inbuilt function to cast Null values out to a data type and check that.

Comment: Feel free to remove the downvote and accept when you figure out how to use this ;)

Comment: How did you try it?  You should be using `IF (ISNULL(@prevfldSubDepartmentID)  = 0 OR (@prevfldSubDepartmentID != paramSubDepartmentID))`

Comment: weird. As per the need I need to use - `(ISNULL(@prevfldSubDepartmentID) = 1 OR (@prevfldSubDepartmentID != paramSubDepartmentID))` instead of `IF (ISNULL(@prevfldSubDepartmentID) = 0 OR (@prevfldSubDepartmentID != paramSubDepartmentID))`  no?

Comment: `= 0` seems to not cause any error but that is not what we want right? I tried `= 1` and `!= 0`. The error is the same :(

Comment: It seems I need null safe not equal operator - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234854/mysql-null-safe-not-equal-operator but it is really weird why both our approach is not working as expected.

Comment: DAustin, it seems the error is coming from [statements;] part. I will get back with more info when this is sorted right. Thanks

Comment: Ah yes it should be = 1 not 0 sorry, good spot!

It may also be that you don't need to check the value as it is a boolean, so maybe `(ISNULL(@prevfldSubDepartmentID) OR (@prevfldSubDepartmentID != paramSubDepartmentID))` without any equality operation would work?

Comment: The error was caused by [statements;] part and the SQL in question was working fine. Using Inbuilt function is a good improvement. The question is not relevant here. I will delete it shortly. Thanks DAustin for your help!